# Google's admin SDK directory API - 403 Not authorized

Tags: python, api, google-api, google-api-python-client

I am having issues with using Google's directory API to pull a list of users from a email group.  Here is my code:

```
CLIENT_SECRET = 'group_auth.p12'
CLIENT_EMAIL = "USER@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
with open(CLIENT_SECRET, "rb") as f:
    PRIVATE_KEY = f.read()
f.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(CLIENT_EMAIL, PRIVATE_KEY, scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly")

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build("admin", "directory_v1", http)
request = service.members().get(groupKey=*taken-out*, memberKey="")
response = request.execute()
```

This is the error i am receiving:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "oauth2client.util"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google_group_membership.py", line 21, in <module>
    response = request.execute()
  File "/Users/jleung/googleapi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jleung/googleapi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 729, in execute
raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting     https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/itgroup%40appdynamics.com/members/?alt=json returned "Not Authorized to access this resource/api">
```

In my google console, I made sure my Google API Service Account has the correct permissions.  Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, I had to go to my google domain admin panel and under security settings -> Advanced Settings -> Manage API client access

I had to add my client ID and the scope in there